# transmit libpqxx::result over network

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am writing an application where client nodes access a postgres database via an intermediary application. The clients cannot query the database directly; instead the intermediary application receives queries from the clients over a network, runs them, and relays the results.

libpqxx's `pqxx::result`, `pqxx::row` and `pqx::field` classes provides many conversion routines that allow the results of queries to be translated into c++ variables. I'd like my client application to make use of these, but that requires somehow either transferring the pqxx objects over the network, or sending the underlying "[flexible textual format](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/a01429.html)", and constructing pqxx objects from this on the client.

'Textual data' is generally simple enough to send over a network, but I can't see any way to access it from the `pqxx::result` objects, or any way to construct pqxx objects from that data were I able to access and transfer it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: TLDR: no there isn't. You must do all the work yourself to serialize and deserialize the results.

Comment: That'd be disappointing if so. There's a lot of work to duplicate all libpqxx's conversion routines. Still, if that's the case then I suppose it can't be helped...